# XML stylesheet - Web Service

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt

I use a web service from my company to display some informations about employees (like Adress Book in Outlook). So i create a little HTML form that POST the web service. I receive the data i want but in an XML tree with a classical "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

I know it's not a real error but i want to display correctly these data for my users. (of course i can't add an xls directly in the web service because i don't have access to it)

Here what kind of xml i receive if it can help :

`<ArrayOfAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://wdi-ws.disney.com/02/2009">
    <Account>
    <AccountName>ACREPIN</AccountName>
    <Email>ALEXANDRE.CREPIN@disney.com</Email>
    <FirstName>ALEXANDRE</FirstName>
    <LastName>CREPIN</LastName>
    <FullName>CREPIN, ALEXANDRE</FullName>
    <DistinguishedName>
CN=CREPIN\, ALEXANDRE,OU=Users,OU=Backstage,OU=FRMV,OU=FR,DC=emea,DC=wdpr,DC=disney,DC=com
    </DistinguishedName>
    <Domain>emea</Domain>
    <City/>
    <Address/>
    <Company>DLP</Company>
    <Department>400300</Department>
    <EmployeeID>S187292</EmployeeID>
    <Telephone>47582</Telephone>
    <Groups/>
    <Title>187292</Title>
    <IsValid>true</IsValid>
    </Account>
    </ArrayOfAccount>`

Thank you in advance and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you start the xml document with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But any browser will just show the XML as raw data if no stylesheet is present and show that "error", meaning that it's just raw xml and not an actual page meant to be viewed in a browser.

An example of a styled xml file: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/001/doc.xml
More information: https://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to follow the example for styled xml file. But it's a Web Service, so i can't modify it to add an xls or a style into the xml document :/

Comment: You should also be able to apply XSL to the file by including it. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp